# Python Inheritance Only working in init

Tags: python, inheritance, maya

I recently posted a question about inheritance but it never got a correct answer so I'm trying again.

I have this code here:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import jtAutoRigUI

class RigLegs(jtAutoRigUI.RigUI):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        jtAutoRigUI.RigUI.__init__(self)
        self.rigLegs()

    def rigLegs(self):
        self.items["side"] = "left"
        self.lIK = cmds.duplicate(self.lJoints["hip"], n = self.getName("hip_IK"))
        self.lIK = cmds.listRelatives(self.lIK, ad = True, type = "joint")
        for i in self.lIK:
            newName = i.replace("_JNT", "_IK")
            cmds.rename(i, newName)
```

And that works for `self.items["side"] = "left"` because it's declared in the init method. But anything declared outside of the init method isn't picked up by inheritance. So when it gets to self.lJoints["hip"] it errors out.

```
class RigUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets = {}
        self.items = {}
        self.items["side"] = "center"
        self.interface()
```

Comment: Have `self.lJoints` *and* `self.lJoints["hip"]` been initialized prior to the call to `self.rigLegs()`?  Values in Python don't spring into existence with default values.  They have to be initialized or you can expect to receive a `NameError`/`AttributeError`/`KeyError`.  (Knowing which one you receive here would be helpful.)

Comment: ?? I don't really know what you're saying. Of course self.lJoints["hip"] has been, otherwise I wouldn't be trying to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "declared outside of the init method"? In general, variables aren't declared in Python. You just set a variable, and after that happens, the variable exists.

Comment: Show us the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: There really isn't an exact error, I'm trying this from so many angles. I've moved onto new style classes and now it thinks everything belongs to the RigLegs class when it shouldn't due to inheritance. All I've done is put `super(jtAutoRigUI.RigUI, self).__init__()` instead of `jtAutoRigUI.RigUI.__init__(self)` . But I'm not even sure that's correct.

Comment: `'RigLegs' object has no attribute 'items'` is the error I get now

Comment: @user1090427 The error seems pretty straightforward to me.  Without seeing the definition of `jtAutoRigUI.RigUI` it's going to be difficult to diagnose why that attribute hasn't yet been set.  It might be helpful to `print repr(self.__dict__)` as the first action in `RigLegs.rigLegs()` to determine exactly which attributes have been set on the object at that point.

Comment: Adding `print dir(self)` after `RigUI.__init__` will almost certainly show that there is no `items` defined.

Comment: `super` is better than trying to do it explicitly… but for a trivial inheritance tree it really doesn't matter much. The point is that if you try to access `self.items` before having set `self.items` anywhere, you get an error. Just having some other function that sets `self.items` doesn't matter unless you actually _call_ that function first.

Comment: ok first of all, items IS defined. I define it in the file that isn't shown here due to being massive. It's defined and used multiple times already in that file. Why does everyone keep thinking I haven't set self.items? It has been and I've already said it has been! I can't show the other file because it's just plain too large.

Comment: @user1090427 We don't think it has been set because *the runtime is telling us it hasn't been set.*  Can you show us one location where it is set?  Are you absolutely sure that section of code is even being executed?

Comment: You can't see the code where it's been set. Of course runtime is telling you it isn't since you don't have the code that sets it.

Comment: There I edited the first post with the init method of the class that's being inherited

Comment: Your original problem was an `AttributeError` on `lJoints` when doing `self.lJoints["hip"]`. That one isn't set in either `RigLegs.__init__` or ``RigUI.__init__`, which explains the error. Your new problem about `items`, we're all kind of stabbing in the dark trying to guess what the problem is, because all we know is that you made some unspecified change to the code and now you're getting that problem.

Comment: @user1090427 You gave us the error from the runtime: `'RigLegs' object has no attribute 'items'`.  Either this is the actual error or it's not, but the runtime doesn't lie -- the `items` attribute had not been set on the object at the time you tried to access it.  That fact cannot be disputed.

Answer (score 2):

The error you started with was apparently an `AttributeError` on `lJoints` in this line:

```
self.lIK = cmds.duplicate(self.lJoints["hip"], n = self.getName("hip_IK"))
```

Let's forget about any later errors from any vaguely-described changes you've made and solve this problem.

The error is telling you that `self` does not have an attribute named `lJoints`, but you're trying to modify `self.lJoints` in some way. (In particular, you're calling its `__getitem__` method, but that isn't important here.)

Now that you've shown us enough of the code to see how this is initialized, the reason is clear: you never initialize `self.lJoints` before calling this function.

Let's trace through it:

First, `RigJoint.__init__()` does this:

```
jtAutoRigUI.RigUI.__init__(self)
```

Now, `RigUI.__init__()` does this:

```
self.widgets = {}
self.items = {}
self.items["side"] = "center"
self.interface()
```

Unless that `interface` method sets `lJoints`, it's still not set at this point.

So, that function returns, and we're back to `RigJoint.__init__()`, which does this:

```
self.rigLegs()
```

So, now we go into `RigJoint.rigLegs()`:

```
self.items["side"] = "left"
```

That doesn't set `self.lJoints`.

```
self.lIK = cmds.duplicate(self.lJoints["hip"], n = self.getName("hip_IK"))
```

And that tries to use `self.lJoints`, which doesn't exist. Hence the `AttributeError`.

---

If you don't understand why this gets an error, try breaking it down into separate lines (always a good step when debugging things):

```
lJoints = self.lJoints
hip = self.lJoints["hip"]
name = self.getName("hip_IK")
dup = cmds.duplicate(hip, name)
self.lIK = dup
```

Now you can see which statement gets the exception, and it's the first one, which should be a lot easier to debug than the original complex statement.

Comment: lJoints is set in a later definition in the original file, but as I said it's too large to post - suppose I can pastebin it though. http://pastebin.com/XBZcX3Fd Have a look at that and see if it makes any more sense? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1090427: OK, so some method called `makeSkeletonLegs` sets `self.lJoints = {}`. But nobody has called `makeSkeletonLegs()` yet at the time you call `rigLegs()`. It looks like that doesn't get called until the user clicks some "Generate Skeleton" button, which obviously hasn't happened yet at the time when you're creating the object and the buttons and so on.

Comment: You have to click Generate Skeleton before you can even call rigLegs() - it's impossible not to because Generate Skeleton ACTIVATES the following buttons. Point is, ultimately, everything HAS been called!

Comment: @user1090427: No, `self.rigLegs()` is called right there in the `RigLegs.__init__()`. (If you're saying that `makeSkeletonLegs` is called on a _different_ `RigUI` object, not the one that's a `RigLegs` object… well, that doesn't help anything. The whole point of OOP is that each object is a self-contained, encapsulated, independent whole. Each `RigUI` is its own separate `self`, and has its own separate `self.lJoints`.) Maybe the problem is just that `__init__` shouldn't be calling `rigLegs`, and that should be triggered by a button or something later on?